# Замена многих вызовов функции на более элегантное решение (цикл)

Tags: c, циклы, url, инспекция-кода

Допустим у меня есть функция для парсинга `Url`, и для того что бы распарсить каждую часть, а так же помимо этого добавить флаг присутствия той или иной части, вызывается одна функция, в которую передается `enum` *(флаги)*, и на данный момент это выглядит примерно так:

```
enum libkodik_url_flag_e {
    libkodik_url_flag_scheme    = 1u << 0u,
    libkodik_url_flag_user      = 1u << 1u,
    libkodik_url_flag_password  = 1u << 2u,
    libkodik_url_flag_host      = 1u << 3u,
    libkodik_url_flag_port      = 1u << 4u,
    libkodik_url_flag_path      = 1u << 5u,
    libkodik_url_flag_query     = 1u << 6u,
    libkodik_url_flag_fragment  = 1u << 7u,
    libkodik_url_flag_max       = 1u << 8u
};

KODIK_CORE_API libkodik_url_t *
libkodik_url_parse(char const *url, int *error) {
    libkodik_url_t* p_data = NULL;

    ...

    uint32_t i_parts_count = 0;

    p_data = libkodik_url_alloc();
    p_data->psz_raw = strdup(url);
    char *psz_part = libkodik_url_parse_part(url, libkodik_url_flag_scheme);

    if(NULL != psz_part) {
        i_parts_count++;
        p_data->i_flags |= libkodik_url_flag_scheme;
        p_data->p_url_parts = realloc(p_data->p_url_parts,
                                      i_parts_count * sizeof(libkodik_url_part_t));
        libkodik_url_write_part(&p_data->p_url_parts[i_parts_count],
                                psz_part, libkodik_url_flag_scheme);
        ...
    } else {
        psz_part = url;
    }

    ...

    *error = 0;
    return p_data;
}
```

Но я хотел бы сделать это дело циклом, т.е. данные там устанавливаются одинаково, но я не понимаю как мне перебрать `enum` в цикле, т.к. он является значением флагов...

Повторяющаяся часть кода:

```
char *psz_part = libkodik_url_parse_part(url, libkodik_url_flag_scheme);

if(NULL != psz_part) {
    i_parts_count++;
    p_data->i_flags |= libkodik_url_flag_scheme;
    p_data->p_url_parts = realloc(p_data->p_url_parts,
                                  i_parts_count * sizeof(libkodik_url_part_t));
    libkodik_url_write_part(&p_data->p_url_parts[i_parts_count],
                            psz_part, libkodik_url_flag_scheme);
    ...
} else {
    psz_part = url;
}
```

**P.S. `libkodik_url_flag_max` не учитывается.**

Comment: Возможно, что-то из этого поможет: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1662719/13970074), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42972791/13970074), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/261963/13970074)

Comment: Ну обычный енумератор перебирать без проблем можно, но когда он является битовыми полями, увы.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, битовые поля могут быть только у `struct` и `union`, а у вас `enum` с обычными числами, только идут они не подряд. Но по ссылкам написано про это

Comment: Ой, перепутал мысль, флаги. `p_data->i_flags`

Comment: Не вижу проблем, может быть всё не так просто? Например так: `for(flag = libkodik_url_flag_scheme ; flag != libkodik_url_flag_max ; flag <<= 1 )..`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, Так... Это же обычное пермножение на 2? Верно?

Comment: Флаг битовой маски равен два в степени X. А смена на другой флаг делается с помощью битового сдвига `<<` или умножением на два. Всё зависит от понятности. `00100b << 1 = 01000b`  или `4 * 2 = 8`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, Напишите ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как флаги у вас идут подряд, можно перебирать циклом просто сдвигая нужный бит. Флаг `libkodik_url_flag_scheme = 1u << 0u` имеет значение `000000001b`. А флаг `libkodik_url_flag_user = 1u << 1u` равен `000000010b`. И наконец последний `libkodik_url_flag_max = 1u << 8u` равен `100000000b`.
Перебираем циклом начиная с первого флага до последнего так :

```
enum libkodik_url_flag_e  flag  ;
for ( flag = libkodik_url_flag_scheme ;
  flag != libkodik_url_flag_max ; flag <<= 1 )
  /* нужная работа со значением флага flag */;
```

На следующий флаг переходим с помощью битового сдвига `<<= 1`. И если был флаг `flag = 000010000b`. То с помощью `flag <<= 1` он станет равным `000100000b`.